# How to I convert a Python script to a executable?

Tags: python, executable, py2exe

So far I have tried `bbfreeze`, `cx_freeze`, `py2exe` and `pyInstaller` with no success.

All I want to do is to make the Python script into an executable so that others can see my work without needing to install Python.

And if I have to install any of these that I have listed above, what do I do with the files?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For this you have two choices:

A downgrade to python 2.6. This is generaly undesirable because it is backtracking and may nullify a small portion of your scripts.

Your second option is to use some form of exe converter. I recommend pyinstaller as it seems to have the best results.

Comment: Did you do it on Linux? And what did you do with the files you got?

Comment: This answer should be a comment. :-/

Comment: I have had the very same problem! I worked (or slaved away) for many many days trying to find an anwser. For this you have two choices:

    A downgrade to python 2.6. This is generaly undesirable because it is backtracking and may nullify a small portion of your scripts
    Your second option is to use some form of exe converter. I recommend pyinstaller as it seems to have the best results.

Good luck!

Comment: I did not find any of this usefull at all basicly :/ I mean, i asked if i needed to install any of those i mentiond and what would i do with the files i get.

Answer (score 0):

Those solutions (probably) won't work under Linux. Possibly with WINE, but I'm not sure about that.

If you just want to share the output of the script, you might look at using [Flask](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or some other web framework to host the script. You can display the output however you'd like.

Alternatively, you could provide [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/) or have the recipients [download and install Python](http://python.org/download/)

Comment: Some of these i mention is allso avalable for Linux use. BTW: this script is not for sites, it is a simple script to ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

While some of those scripts are available on Linux, I don't think you can actually build an exe for Windows using it on Linux. So instead, you should create the executable on a machine with the OS you are targeting. Then you can create an installer with Inno Setup (or similar) to make it very easy for the end user to install. Here are a couple of articles I wrote on the process:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/27/packaging-wxpymail-for-distribution/

Comment: I have seen other on Linux who have made executables for other OS's, why would't I?

Comment: I think it depends on what kind of application you're creating. Sometimes py2exe needs to include DLLs for Windows which won't be available on Linux/Mac, for example. If the application depends on some C/C++ headers or similar, then it will compile for Linux, but not necessarily for other OSes

Comment: I think that they used "cx_freeze" or "pyInstaller". If i choose one of them, what will I do with the files I get?

Comment: I would just copy them to a USB drive and try them out on a different OS to see if they work. You could put them in a zip file if you wanted to make it easier to distribute

Comment: I don't have any other OS, because Windows is BS me, and mac costs too much for me.